# Value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{j}{n})$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

If $f$ is continuous in [0,1] then what will be the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)?$$

We know that,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{{n}}\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$But what will be the value if we have $\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]$ instead of $n?$

Comment: Hint: $\left[\frac{n}{2}\right] = \frac{n}{2}$ or $\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. Try with both cases and check whether it really matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Idea:** Try to massage it into the Riemann sum for another continuous function $g$, closely  related to $g$, by a "change of variables" $u=\frac{x}{2}$.

**In detail.** Assume without loss of generality that $n$ is even *(why can you do so? Check it does not change anything)*, i.e. $n=2m$.
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{1}{m}f\left(\frac{j}{2m}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\frac{1}{m}g\left(\frac{j}{m}\right)
\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 g
$$
where $g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g(x)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(\frac{x}{2}).$ (In particular, $g$ is continuous.)

Then, we have
$$
\int_0^1 g(u)du = \int_0^1 f(\frac{u}{2})du
= \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 2f(x)dx
$$

so your overall limit will be $
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x)dx
$.

Comment: Now, I'd recommend, as a sanity check, that you verify the result on simple functions like $f(x)=a$ (constant), $f(x)=x$ (identity), and $f(x)=x^2$.